# Check whether there are more even than odd numbers on any given nested list

Tags: code-golf, number

Take any type of nested list(s) containing numbers. Check for how many even/odd numbers are within and output even, same or odd (-1, 0, 1) in some way.

Example:

```
[[1,2,3],4,[5,6],[[7,8], 9]] => 5 odd > 4 even => odd or -1
[1,2,2,1,2,2,2]              => 5 even > 2 odd => even or 1
[1,2,2,1]                    => 2 even = 2 odd => same or 0
```

Comment: Mind clarifying the example (and possibly provide more of them)? Your task description talks about counting odd numbers and filtering out odd numbers, but your example doesn't really show anything of that ilk at all. Also, clarifying how input/output is supposed to work would help.

Comment: And if there are the same number?

Comment: Then say same or 0

Comment: -1 for changing important requirements after people posted their answers. Try to avoid that next time.

Comment: @flodel Boollum didn't do it - minitech, LegoStormtroopr and I did (I rolled it back)

Comment: Also, I've changed my answers to meet the requirements.

Comment: Well then I guess it is a downvote for y'all's contribution...

Comment: The question says “nested list”. From this I understand that recursive evaluation is required, making [[1,1,2],[1,1,2],[1,2,2,2,2]] = [odd,odd,even] = odd. Is this right?

Comment: @manatwork I assummed that that you count the number of odds and evens in the whole list then output the larger value. So for your example, [[1,1,2],[1,1,2],[1,2,2,2,2]] -> [1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2] = even (5 odd, 6 even)

Comment: @Quincunx, as I can tell, the other solutions are also using that interpretation. I think the best would be to rephrase this question as “Take any type of list containing numbers separated by any noise.” – seems that would not disqualify any existing answer. Then BoollumBits could open a new question for real nested list, with good explanation and relevant example.

Answer (score 3):

### Python - 63

This returns a negative number if its got more evens, `0` if their are an equal amount or a positive number if there are more odds.

```
x=input()
i=0
for o in x:
 try:x+=o
 except:i+=o%2-.5
print i
```

edit: Type checking, who needs that, lets just stab blindly.

Comment: Wouldn’t `list` be shorter than `type([])`?

Comment: @minitech yes it would :)

Comment: @minitech not type checking is even shorter!

Comment: This doesn't return `even` or `odd`, as required.

Comment: @Timtech: It says “indicate in some way” and the example shown isn’t exactly regular output, so…

Comment: @minitech Time to shorten my answers. =)

Comment: To be fair, I was the one who edited it to say "indicate in some way" as the original question was very ambiguous on that front.

Comment: Lol, editing it for your purpose. Fine though, you defined it better.

Comment: @Timtech all making people say 'odd' or 'even' will do is at least 7 (usually more) characters to their code. This way its truer to the idea of golf.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this would work with a nested list. NEVERMIND. I see. That's very clever! Should be noted that if you use this then you sabotage the list!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Yes, I agree. I've removed these from my answers.

Answer (score 1):

### R 58

This was written at a time the OP was asking for two "even" or "odd" possible outputs.

```
function(x)c("even","odd")[which.max(table(unlist(x)%%2))]
```

Example usage:

```
(function(x)c("even","odd")[which.max(table(unlist(x)%%2))])(
   list(list(1, 2, 3), 4, list(5, 6), list(list(7, 8), 9)))
# [1] "odd"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 98 - 19

```
&2%6*j\1+\2j1+3j@.`
```

Outputs 1 if even, 0 if odd or the same. I'm still trying to figure out how to indicate that they are the same. However, I have not tested this because I don't have a Befunge 98 compiler. It works as follows:

```
&   receives input as a number, all parts that aren't numbers are ignored and skipped
2%  takes that number and divides it by two, then gets the remainder (1 if odd, 0 if even)
6*j jump 6 characters if odd, 0 if even

when even:
\   swap top two numbers on stack (I'm storing evens under the odds)
1+  add one to that value
\   swap back
2j  jump 2 characters

when odd:
1+  add 1 to top number on stack

3j  jump 3 characters (to end of line ie the beginning (Befunge wraps))
```

When `&` is hit again, if there are no more values, it acts like a reflector, sending the instruction pointer back the other way and running this:

```
@.`
```

(executed in reverse order):

```
` compares the even and odd values, if even is greater, then push 1, else 0
. prints it out
@ ends the program
```

---

With one simple change, it can be made to print some negative number if there are more odds, some positive number if there are more evens, and 0 if there are the same amount:

```
&2%6*j\1+\2j1+3j@.-
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 64

#### three possible outputs

```
function(x)c("even","same","odd")[sign(mean(unlist(x)%%2)-.5)+2]
```

Examples:

```
(function(x)c("even","same","odd")[sign(mean(unlist(x)%%2)-.5)+2])(
   list(list(1, 2, 3), 4, list(5, 6), list(list(7, 8), 9)))
[1] "odd"

(function(x)c("even","same","odd")[sign(mean(unlist(x)%%2)-.5)+2])(
   list(list(2, 3), 4))
[1] "even"

(function(x)c("even","same","odd")[sign(mean(unlist(x)%%2)-.5)+2])(
  list(list(2, 3), list(4, 5)))
[1] "same"
```

Answer (score 1):

## k

34 characters.

Outputs `o` for odd, `e` for even, `s` for same.

```
{"ose"1+{(x>0)-x<0}@+/-1 xexp,//x}
```

```
{(`s#-0w -.5 .5!"ose")@+/-1 xexp,//x}
```

Example:

```
{"ose"1+{(x>0)-x<0}@+/-1 xexp,//x}((1 3;5 10);12 2 4 6 8)
"e"
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Golf-Basic 84](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1261), 17

```
i`Ad`fpart(A/2)*2
```

Returns `0`s for even numbers and `1`s for odd numbers. Accepts nested arrays -  1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, etc.

---

**Old version, 30 characters:**

```
i`A@fpart(A/2)*2t`ODD"#t`EVEN"
```

**Explanation** (for old version)

```
i`A
```

Store input in A. Accepts arrays, e.g. `{1,2,3,4}` or `{{1,2},3,{4,5,{6,7}},8}`

```
@fpart(A/2)*2t`ODD"#t`EVEN"
```

If (`@`) one or more numbers in array `A` are odd, display `ODD`. Else (`#`) display `EVEN`.

Comment: *“If (@) one or more numbers in array A are odd, display ODD. Else (#) display EVEN.”* That’s not the challenge. The idea is to check whether there are more even numbers than odd numbers.

Comment: @minitech WHAT?!?! Someone SERIOUSLY edited the question!!!

Comment: @minitech Nevermind, **that was the old version**. The new one outputs `1`s for odd and `0`s for even.

Comment: I think that might be taking “indicate in some way” a little far :D

Comment: @minitech I might as well, taken that Golf-Basic 84 actually runs through every digit in the array every time I put it into a mathematical equation (e.g. modulus).

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 65

```
c=l=>l.reduce((a,b)=>a+(+b?b%2-.5:c(b)),0),l=>c(l)<0?"even":"odd"
```

Defaults to “odd” if there are equal numbers of each. Requires arrow function support, which currently means “SpiderMonkey”.

If you don’t mind output as a number, it’s just this part, at **42**:

```
c=l=>l.reduce((a,b)=>a+(+b?b%2-.5:c(b)),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ti-Basic 84, 26 characters

```
:Input A:Disp fpart(A/2)*2
```

Returns `1` for odd numbers and `0` for even numbers. Takes nested arrays - 1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, 5D, etc.

---

Old version, **50** characters:

```
:Input A:If fpart(A/2)*2:Disp"ODD":Else:Disp"EVEN"
```

Takes arrays like `{1,2,3}` and also `{1,{2,3},4,{5,{6,7}},{{8,9},10},11}`

Returns `EVEN` for all even and `ODD` if it contains odd.

Comment: The **new version** complies with the new requirements of measuring how many odd and even numbers there are (it displays an array of true and false).

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 51+

#### Variation 1, 61 or 51

Reads input via `prompt`, outputs via `alert`, encodes answer as a number with sign denoting if more evens or odds.

```js
b=0;prompt().replace(/\d+/g,function(s){b+=s%2*2-1});alert(b) // ES5, 61
b=0;prompt().replace(/\d+/g,s=>b+=s%2*2-1);alert(b) // ES6, 51
```

#### Variation 2, 72 or 49

As above, but as a function taking an array instead of using `prompt`/`alert`.

```js
function f(s){b=0;return s.big?b+=s%2*2-1:s.join().replace(/\d+/g,f)&&b} // ES5, 72
f=a=>b=0,a.join().replace(/\d+/g,s=>b+=s%2*2-1),b // ES6, 49
```